# combinatorics sequence without mirrored solutions

Tags: math, combinations, combinatorics

Are there any way to calculate the unique number of integer sequences for a given length of integers?

With unique, I mean where `100` and `001` are considered the same sequence.

I tested it by hand up to 6, but didn't see any patterns

```
3 gave 6
4 gave 10
5 gave 18 
6 gave 36
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please define "unique number of integer sequences for a given length of integers". I can think of multiple possible meanings for that vague phrase. Also, what does this have to do with computer programming?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got it wrong at n = 5. It should be 20, not 18.
The number of unique binary sequences of length n (n = 1, 2, ...) is
2, 3, 6, 10, 20, 36, 72, 136, ...

There is a formula for it, check out https://oeis.org/A005418

To be explicit, the formula is `2^(n - 1) + 2^(floor((n + 1)/2) - 1)` where `floor()` is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

(BTW. This should probably be moved to [math](https://math.stackexchange.com))